# Explain why a new radiator cap fixed my coolant leak

Tags: honda, coolant, radiator, leak

I have a newly acquired 2010 Honda Odyssey. As part of the purchase, the seller replaced the timing belt and water pump. From the moment I acquired the car, it lost coolant continuously. I needed to add a cup of coolant every couple of days to keep the level in the reserve tank above the MIN line.

There were no visible leaks in any hose, nor in the radiator. The front of the engine was dry. The coolant transfer pipe under the intake manifold and the cylinder valley was dry. There was no odor of coolant inside the car. There was no steam from the tailpipe, and both the coolant and motor oil appeared normal (pristine, in fact). There were no puddles on the ground.

While the engine was hot, I inspected every hose in the engine compartment, as well as the hoses to the rear heater core. All were bone dry.

I replaced the radiator cap and the coolant loss stopped.

This car has a DENSO radiator cap, which has three gaskets. A main gasket seals the cap to the radiator neck. The pressure control valve has a gasket that seals to the inner neck, and the vacuum valve has an internal gasket:

[image: Denso Cap Diagram]

Looking at the cap diagram, it seem obvious that the the pressure valve was not maintaining pressure (the cap was the original, now 14-year old, cap).

My question is, why did coolant being expelled through the pressure valve not make its way into the reserve tank? It has been very cold during this time (daytime temperatures below freezing), so my theory is that the coolant was boiling off the radiator and being emitted as vapor, probably escaping from the unsealed recovery tank, and possibly through a leaking cap seal as well.

Looking for confirmation or other thoughts.

EDIT: Original cap shows heavily dried and distorted pressure control valve gasket; not surprising that it wasn't sealing well:

[image: knackered radiator cap]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm wondering if it was just a coincidence that the cap replacement coincided with the system finishing "burping" itself from the refill of the system after water pump replacement?

Comment: I thought about that. I did remove the cap earlier and the coolant was right to the top of the radiator. Also, I assume that if you do have air in the system and a leaky cap, it will ultimately get expelled through the overflow house (and then suck coolant back into the system from the reserve tank). But the burp should be a one-time deal; this coolant loss went on for a couple of weeks.